# How do I manipulate the Javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I want to manipulate the array with sample data.

What I'm trying to do is find the movieId in the votes data, count it, get the user's name

**Data Description:**

movieId: votes have multiple movieIds, but only need to import one.

movieIdLength: total number of movieId's.

name: User name with the same movieId.

**For example:**

```
var votes = [{

    "id": 1,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 2,
    "name": "James"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 3,
    "name": "Laura"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 1,
    "name": "Dan"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 3,
    "name": "Steve"
}]
```

**what I want:**

```
var votesResult = [{

    "movieId": 2,
    "movieIdLength": 1,
    "name": "James"
},{
    "movieId": 1,
    "movieIdLength": 1,
    "name": "Dan"
},{
    "movieId": 3,
    "movieIdLength": 2,
    "name": "Laura, Steve"
}]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with REST?

Comment: You want the data to be filtered locally or from rest api ?

Comment: You need to start with an empty list for the result array, then you loop over the data and check if the movie id is in the result list. is it is, then count movieIdCount up by 1 and append the name to the name field, otherwise add a new movie to the result array, do you want the algorithm?

Comment: @Benjaco Your question is correct.

Comment: @parkwookyun i will post it as a answer

Comment: @PrateekGupta Your question is correct, but a more accurate question is here.

Comment: @Amy I agree with your opinion. So I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

ES6:

```js
const a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 2,
    "name": "James"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 3,
    "name": "Laura"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 1,
    "name": "Dan"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 3,
    "name": "Steve"
}]

const r = [...new Set(a.map(x => x.movieId))]
 .map(x => Object.assign({movieId: x}, 
   {movieIdLength: a.filter(l => l.movieId === x).length}, 
   {name: a.filter(q => q.movieId === x).map(n => n.name).join(', ')}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2));
```

Less clear but without code duplication:

```js
const a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 2,
    "name": "James"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 3,
    "name": "Laura"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 1,
    "name": "Dan"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "pollId": 1,
    "movieId": 3,
    "name": "Steve"
}]

const r = [...new Set(a.map(x => x.movieId))]
  .map(x => Object.assign({movieId: x}, 
  ((f) => Object.assign({movieIdLength: f.length, name: f.map(({name}) => name).join(', ')})
    )(a.filter(({movieId}) => movieId === x))
  ));

console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with an empty list for the result array, then you loop over the data and check if the movie id is in the result list. is it is, then count movieIdCount up by 1 and append the name to the name field, otherwise add a new movie to the result array, do you want the algorithm?